# How Do Sort My Json Array in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a sorted Json Array:

```
_bb = 

[
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "2",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  }
]
```

And I'm using this Common table expression to group and arrange 'pos'.

```
with j(_bb) as (values(_con))
, ord(o,v) as (values(1,'Top'),(2,'Left'),(3,'Content'),(4,'Right'),(5,'Bottom'))
, un as (select *,jsonb_array_elements(_con) i from j)
select jsonb_agg(i order by o) from un
join ord on v=i->>'pos' into _test;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is after grouping and arranging the orders based on the 'pos' value. I want to also arrange them based on their 'so' value. `_test` returns a sorted value based on 'pos'.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
[
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "2",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  },
   {
    "so": "2",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  }
]
```

Comment: You can create a single column dynamically "pos_num" with 1,2,3,4,5 position and put it according to there "pos" and than make it order by pos_num.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just needed to add another order by `i->>'so'`

```
   with j(_bb) as (values([
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "2",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  },
   {
    "so": "2",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  }
]::jsob))
    , ord(o,v) as (values(1,'Top'),(2,'Left'),(3,'Content'),(4,'Right'),(5,'Bottom'))
    , un as (select *,jsonb_array_elements(_bb) i from j)
    select jsonb_agg(i order by o,i->>'so') from un
    join ord on v=i->>'pos';
```